# What is the realism level of never needing to defecate?

Tags: internal-consistency, creature-design, anatomy, humanoid

So I was thinking about making a 'artificial', 6 inch tall, humanoid creature that not only never really makes feces/urine, but is able to pretty much eat grass(or any other plants humans cannot digest right) like a cow. Why? Because it is cool and I am vegetarian, and if I stick with their, the Bragoda-ningyo-dolls(literally Doll-doll-doll from Kotava, Japanese and English respectfully) lore, then having not only no need to use the restroom(if you feed them right), but if you are poor, then having they literally just eating grass and be fine, would be a Heaven-sent feature for the people that 'own' them.

Anyway, they have the ability to produce the enzymes necessary to breakdown cellulose and the like, unlike humans. They also have MASSIVE guts,like they are 50-51 inches long(like 50-51 feet long to us),and that is only if you count the braided-up length of the small intestines. Yes, you heard that right, they have small intestines that are 'braided-up' in a single 'gut' braid to allow them to have the most gut in the least amount of space. As for how long the small intestines are freed-up is something I will calculate later, as I know the braided-up small intestines are around 23 inches long, and the large intestines are around 28 inches long.This very long track of guts basically adsorb every bit of nutrition and water in the food, with only the occasional burp or passage of gas. The only time feces is made is if meat or excessive milk/eggs are given as they cannot handle those well, especially meat.

How realistic is this build barring the negatives of square-cube law?

Comment: Can you add a sketch of what you mean by "braided up"? That would be helpful!

Comment: How is being huge to the point of immobility carrying around all this half-digested food material more efficient than an organism that produces an agriculturally useful waste product? But biologically, if they can produce feces in response to animal proteins, they'll produce it in response to less digestible plant cellulose. Carnivores have simpler digestive systems, and most herbivores can tolerate animal proteins in their diet ( I lone the video of a deer eating a bird...)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQOQdBLHrLk

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something in your rationale, or else this is pretty unrealistic.

Comment: I will show it in a bit.@elemtilas

Comment: Yeah, but they have the enzymes to help break that cellulose down for them, meaning easier digestion and they have equivalently the same stomach space as humans. I think the more efficient processing  will allow the to eat less then we do, maybe. The reason why they poop when they eat meat, or a least a moderate meal of it, is because 1. I am vegetarian and want to villainize meat ;) , and 2. because they have an intolerance to most proteins and stuff in most meats making it hard to digest topped with an REALLY unnecessarily long gut for eating meat leads to a bathroom trip.@DWKraus

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this isn't realistic at all.  One of the features that most herbivore species share is that they are large, or they are poikilothermic (cold blooded).  This is because  digesting cellulose is *hard*.  Even with the right enzymes, whether provided by gut bacteria or directly by the herbivore's digestive system, digesting cellulose is still a time-consuming process which consumes almost as much energy as it yields.

Additionally, the process of extracting energy from high-cellulose plants involves mechanically breaking down the plants to access the cells inside the cellulose cell walls.  This involves chewing with lots of grinding teeth or a rock-filled gizzard.
Alternatively, it can require pre-chewing followed by soaking the chewed food in cellulose-digesting fluids before being chewed again, a process that doesn't require as many teeth as the first option.

In order to yield enough energy for its high-energy lifestyle, a homeothermic (warm blooded) herbivore must eat and digest a lot of high-cellulose food at once.
As metabolic rate per unit mass decreases as size increases, and the energy yields of digesting cellulose increases with size, it makes sense for grass-eating herbivores to evolve to be large.  Alternatively, a low-energy poikilothermic creature may be smaller, as its lower energy requirements per unit mass may be met by a smaller mass of digesting cellulose.

Alternatively, many smaller herbivores resort to eating lower-cellulose, higher-energy parts of plants, such as their fruits and seeds.  However, the grass that the OP  says that these miniature humanoids would eat is neither low-cellulose nor particularly high-energy fodder.

Rabbits are an example of a low body-mass herbivore which eats low quality food.  However, rabbits cope with their diet by eating some of their own feces, effectively doubling the length of their digestive tracts.  They can tell the difference between feces that has been through their gut once or twice, and do not eat feces that has made a second pass.

So, already these are points against 6-inch grass-eating humanoids.  I'm pretty sure that the OP envisions slender creatures, proportioned much as a full-sized human  but an even remotely plausible six-inch tall bipedal humanoid adapted to eating grass would likely appear more rotund than the most morbidly obese human alive, and while it may not suffer from the deleterious effects of obesity, it would be neither particularly athletic nor energetic, as a common trait of small herbivores is that they tend to be slow and lethargic due to the lack of readily available energy, sloths and koalas being exemplars of this lifestyle.  It would also not have a flat, human-like face, but would have a muzzle more reminiscent of that of a baboon in order to house the battery of teeth required.

Next, we must address the issue of a *lack* of defecation that the OP describes.  This is again unrealistic.  Firstly, high-cellulose plant matter contains a lot of stuff that isn't cellulose... stuff like lignin which makes plants woody, which is even harder to digest.  Secondly, animals never completely digest their food, as it doesn't make metabolic sense to do so.  By digesting their food *just enough*, they can achieve the greatest possible energy surplus that makes eating their chosen food worthwhile.  However, while digesting the indigestibles may be *possible*, the metabolic cost of doing so would be greater than the energy that would be released.  *Completely* digesting a foodstuff may be so costly that it would take more energy to achieve than would be released, making the creature literally starve in the process.

So... creatures defecate because they would have less (or no) surplus energy, or an energy *deficit* from their food if they did.

For a six-inch humanoid that the OP would probably like to be active and energetic, and probably be homeothermic, this wouldn't leave much energy for that lifestyle, if any at all.

The OP's argument for this creature defecating only/more if it eats animal products is also unrealistic.  Animal products, lacking a cellulose cell wall, yield far more energy in return for the metabolic cost of digesting them than plant matter, without requiring different digestive enzymes.  Any herbivore can eat meat (and some do when the opportunity arises), though foregut fermenters like cows would need to restrict their intake lest the rich food cause a painful or fatal digestive imbalance.  Given that meat and animal products (other than bones) are so easily digestible, there will always be less waste matter left over once such a meal has been digested than would be the case for a meal of plant matter.

Next, we need to address not producing urine.
Water is an unavoidable byproduct of some metabolic processes, so to not excrete it would lead to fluid retention and would eventually be fatal.  The total volume of urine can be minimized by producing more concentrated urine, but this would also be more visible and odourous.

So, this six-inch-tall herbivorous humanoid, if it could exist at all, would probably not be an active, entertaining miniature human, but would more likely be a rotund, sluggish, lazy, couch-potato of a creature with a long muzzle and probably a pungent aroma, that would need to spend much of its time eating grass rather than being an entertaining pet.  It wouldn't likely be able to afford the metabolic cost of a large brain, so it wouldn't be particularly intelligent either.

All this is not considering the problem of thermoregulation.  Such a small body would lose heat quickly (due to the higher ratio of surface area to volume due to the square-cube law) unless it was furry or lived in a very warm environment.  This thing is looking less and less human - or practical - at every stage.

Answer (score 1):

## This can be done, but it requires a vastly superior metabolism, and some cheating.

Digesting cellulose is hard.  For *Terrans*.  If you had the right set of enzymes, it might be easier.  For example, a wood burning stove can digest cellulose, lignins, and all else in a log down to an occasional shovelful of ashes.  The ashes are hard to avoid without transmutation - elements like potassium and phosphorus are going in, so how do they go out?

I am, therefore, going to cheat and say your adorable little pets have a habit of getting into trouble and having *sneezing fits*.  They cough little bits of dust, the rough counterpart of wood burner ash, that they did not breathe in.  If you make a very cute animation drawing, the characters will almost forget that they are being dusted with poo.  Done well it shouldn't have a bad smell or taste anyway, I think.

How do they have these ultimate enzymes?  Well, I'm going to suggest that instead of our amino acids formed into proteins, they have a series of robust modules that can be repositioned "on the fly" using complex electromagnetic fields at the micron scale.  As a result, when biology turns to "polymer science" to try to make something that can't easily be unmade - like reacting aromatic compounds into lignins, melanin, humic acid etc. - then *these* enzymes can simply scan the molecule, do a computation to determine which structures to fold into to precisely match the local geometry, and then take them apart atom by atom.  They may also have a broader range of elements in their biochemistry to give them more powerful catalytic options.

Bear in mind that there are planets out there more than twice as old as Earth.  Our system of ribosomes and other organelles may seem impressive to us, but with time and a lot of luck they may have done substantially better.

Answer (score 0):

**Unrealistic.**

Every real animal needs to defecate, regardless of its size or diet. So an animal that never defecates is unrealistic.